# Is this hint for proving the fundamental theorem of coalgebras wrong?

Tags: abelian-categories, coalgebras

In the book [Tensor Categories](https://math.mit.edu/%7Eetingof/egnobookfinal.pdf), Exercise 1.9.4 is to prove the fundamental theorem of coalgebras. They give the following hint:

[image: Tensor Categories Exercise 1.9.4]

This hint doesn't make sense to me. You can always add and subtract a term from the sum to make the span larger, so this supposed subcoalgebra depends on how I represent the comultiplication.

In particular, in order for the span to always give a subcoalgebra, it would need to be the case that every finite dimensional subspace containing the subcoalgebra generated by $c$ is itself a subcoalgebra, which is clearly false.

Am I missing something or misunderstanding the hint? Do they mean the intersection of all such spans, or something like that?

I know how to prove the exercise without the hint, such as how its proven in Montgomery's book, but this hint is very weird to me and isn't mentioned in the errata.

Comment: Try it with all sum presentations.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg would that not just give the whole coalgebra C?

Comment: Why? I mean all sum presentations of that particular element. You can also have a look at other proofs of that theorem by the way.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Does sum presentation imply some linear independence of the terms or something? Cause otherwise can't I just always add $x \otimes x \otimes x - x \otimes x \otimes x$ to a sum presentation to force the span to include any $x$?

Comment: After thinking about this more, linear independence is the key. If we pick a basis of $C$ and force the $c_i^{(1)}$ and $c_i^{(3)}$ to be basis elements, this fixes the values of the $c_i^{(2)}$. And then its not hard to show that the span of the $c_i^{(2)}$ doesn't depend on the choice of basis, so we get a well-defined subspace.

Comment: I still think its a little misleading to just call this the span of the $c_i^{(2)}$ without mentioning anything about linear independence, but maybe this is a standard abuse of notation?